# AutoCompleteTextView Android Doesn't Work

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

I tried to implement a `AutoCompleteTextView` populated by options available into a Sqlite database.

I made a Get method using this code:

```
    //Get Concelhos to Search Autocomplete
public ArrayList<String> getListConcelhos() {
    ArrayList<String> listaConcelhos = new ArrayList<>();

    dbase = this.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = dbase.rawQuery("SELECT DISTINCT CONCELHO FROM " + TABLE_NAME, null);
    //cursor.moveToFirst();

    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        String value = cursor.getString(
                cursor.getColumnIndex("CONCELHO"));

        listaConcelhos.add(new String(value));  // TENTAR
    }


    return listaConcelhos;

}
```

And call it into my activity using this:

```
    dbHelper = new DbHelper(this);
        listaConcelhos = dbHelper.getListConcelhos();
String[] arrayConcelhos = listaConcelhos.toArray(new String[listaConcelhos.size()]);
        text=(AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView1);
        ArrayAdapter adapter = new
                ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,arrayConcelhos);
        text.setAdapter(adapter);
        text.setThreshold(1);
```

But don't work, the drop-down list is not presented with options.
I made a Log to verify if get method returned the information and the info is returned correctly.

```
Log.e("LOG: ", listaConcelhos.toString());
```

I tried another example, using a hardcoded String[] and this way work:

```
String[] concelhos = {"Concelho 1", "Concelho2"};

text=(AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextViewConcelhos);
ArrayAdapter adapter = new
ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,concelhos);
text.setAdapter(adapter);
text.setThreshold(1);
```

Why my initial implementation using the get method doesn't work? And using a hardcoded String[] work?

Can you help me to resolve this problem?

Thanks

Comment: Have you checked that your generated list is not empty?

Comment: Yes, i checked it using Log.e("LOG: ", listaConcelhos.toString()); and are presented all info loaded from database.

Comment: why new String(value) in  listaConcelhos.add(new String(value));  why don't you add only value to list?

Comment: show us what log is returning

Comment: Log Return this: "LOG: Concelho 1, Concelho 2, Concelho 3 and that coincide with information selected from the database column